# Editing edit-tags.php page in wp-admin

Tags: wp-admin, tags

I want to edit the edit-tags.php, particularly the post_tag page. I want to add some content as shown in the pic below.

[image]

I have found the way to detect the page with the [get_current_screen](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen) function, but I'm clueless what to do next. The only thing I can think of is using Javascript to add the element, but that would be hack-ish.

How do you edit the content in edit-tags.php?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dynamic `{$taxonomy}_term_new_form_tag` action, where you replace `{$taxonomy}` with your taxonomy slug.

**Example<sup>1)</sup>**

For the `post_tag` taxonomy:

```
add_action( 'post_tag_term_new_form_tag', function()
{
    printf( '><div class="form-field">%s</div', esc_html__( 'Some content', 'mydomain' ) );
}, PHP_INT_MAX );
```

*1) Update:*

I didn't noticed at first that this is inside the `<form>` tag, so this is a hack to adjust to that and the `PHP_INT_MAX` priority is here to run it as late as possible. But I don't like this approach, the `{$taxonomy}_add_form_fields` is more suitable, but then you would need to move it up via CSS (flex order?) or javascript.

It's also possible to hijack the fourth `esc_attr()` call, after `post_tag_term_new_form_tag` is fired up, via the `attribute_escape` filter, i.e. the one inside the `wp_nounce_field()` but that sounds too unstable.

Answer (score 1):

Was running into a similar issues with a Custom Taxonomy. Ended up going with this:

```
add_action('tax_name_pre_add_form', 'custom_content');
function custom_content() {
    echo 'Insert Content';
}
```

It should add the content where you wanted.